# How to beautify binary dict files?

Tags: keyboard, settings, preferences

I've opened `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict` in vim, and it looks like jibberish. Is there a way to convert it to human readable just to see what it contains?

Answer (score 4):

If you have plutil installed

You can run this Applescript which will create a text version of the dictionary for you to read.

```
   property copyScriptPath : "~/Documents/" (* path dir for text version*)

tell application "Finder"
    set selectFiles to (get selection) (* get the finder selection*)
end tell
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in selectFiles
    (* convert to POSIX path*)
    set this_item to quoted form of POSIX path of (item i of selectFiles as alias)


    (* get the file name , add it to an alias, then use plutil to read and write atext version out using the original name*)
    do shell script "name=`basename " & this_item & "`;/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1  " & this_item & " -o  " & copyScriptPath & "\"$name\".txt"
end repeat
```

---

OR

There is an old hint on [macosxhints - 10.4: Edit binary (and normal) plist files with vim](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050803111126899)

The post also has the link to the [vim script](http://hints.macworld.com/dlfiles/vim_plist_script.txt) that does all this.

Which may do what you want. ( don't use vim myself )

Quote from the post ( But please go and read it as there are comments and notes that you will need:

> What does it do? It reads a plist file, checks and memorizes if it is
>   binary, converts it to plain text if necessary and turns on syntax
>   highlinghting for XML. When you save the file again, it is converted
>   to binary again for writing if it was binary in the beginning. If the
>   file was not binary or if the conversion to binary fails (which can
>   happen if you have syntax errors in your file), the file is stored in
>   text format. If an originally-binary plist is saved as plain text due
>   to syntax errors and you fix the errors and save the file again, it is
>   written in binary format. If you open a binary file and just view it
>   without making any changes, you can still exit from vim using the
>   normal :q (no need for :q!) and the file is left untouched (still in
>   binary format). All this should work even when working with several
>   buffers (files), when reading a file into an existing buffer, or when
>   only writing parts of a buffer to file

---

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file to some other directory. Move to that directory and run

```
plutil -convert xml1 StandardKeyBinding.dict
```

in terminal. (You may convert it to `json` format by replacing `xml1` with `json`.)
Then run

```
cat -v StandardKeyBinding.dict
```

and you can see the file in a readable manner now, like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>^C</key>
    <string>insertNewline:</string>
    <key>^H</key>
    <string>deleteBackward:</string>
    <key>  </kev>
    <string>insertTab:</string>
    <key>
</key>
    <string>insertNewline:</string>
    <key>^M</key>
    <string>insertNewline:</string>
    <key>^Y</key>
    <string>insertBacktab:</string>
    <key>^[</key>
    <string>cancelOperation:</string>
    <key>$?M-^\M-^@</key>
    <string>moveUpAndModifySelection:</string>
    <key>$?M-^\M-^A</key>
    <string>moveDownAndModifySelection:</string>
    <key>$?M-^\M-^B</keV>
    <string>moveLeftAndModifySelection:</string>
```

Tips: Run `man cat` to see what `cat -v` does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method to make `StandardKeyBinding.dict` file correctly readable:

```
plutil -convert xml1 StandardKeyBinding.dict
```

No use to convert it back.

Comment: You mean no need to convert it back?

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c print /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict
```